# Javascript Chart not drawing on different android api versions

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

while developing an `Android` application that uses [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) to draw some charts, I encountered this weird problem: on Galaxy Nexus S (having OS 4.0.4) the chart draws perfectly, while on a Motorola Defy (CyanogenMod7, having OS  2.3.7) it does not. Could this be an OS version issue? Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
public class RickshawTestActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        webView = new WebView(this);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        setContentView(webView);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chart.html");

    }
}
```

And here is `assets/chart.html`

```
<!doctype>
<script src="vendor/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/d3.layout.min.js"></script>
<script src="rickshaw.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
    var data = [ {
        x : 1910,
        y : 92228531
    }, {
        x : 1920,
        y : 106021568
    }, {
        x : 1930,
        y : 123202660
    }, {
        x : 1940,
        y : 132165129
    }, {
        x : 1950,
        y : 151325798
    }, {
        x : 1960,
        y : 179323175
    }, {
        x : 1970,
        y : 203211926
    }, {
        x : 1980,
        y : 226545805
    }, {
        x : 1990,
        y : 248709873
    }, {
        x : 2000,
        y : 281421906
    }, {
        x : 2010,
        y : 308745538
    } ];

    var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
        element : document.querySelector("#chart"),
        width : 580,
        height : 250,
        series : [ {
            color : 'steelblue',
            data : data
        } ]
    });

    graph.render();
</script>
```

The data is valid, and all the referenced `.js` files are found.
This also works in my Mozilla 13 browser.

Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

I also tested this piece of code on different emulators and concluded that the code above works only on OS versions 3.0 and above. On OS versions below 3.0, this does not work.

Now how can I make it work? Thanks

**EDIT:**
I need a library that is cross-platform.

Comment: What do you mean with cross-platform. Your question is about developing an Android app.

Comment: You really want my 50 rep put on this question, right? :)

Comment: What I want is reuseability on other platforms. Anyway, dude, you could give me this answer, when the bounty was not put on this question, and btw it is not a very great answer, by this I mean it is well documented and stuff, but does not solve my problem. Sorry.

Comment: I don't care about your 50 rep points - I already have enough. I simply want to understand what you are trying to achieve. But it seems like a complete platform independent solution that works everywhere is simply impossible. Therefore you have to split and develop individual solutions for certain platform and/or versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume one ore more features Rickshaw/D3 uses is not (correctly/fully) implemented in the WebKit version shipped with Android prior to 3.0. As Webkit is part of the OS you can not change or update it separately.

The only chance you have is using a different web browser app that has it's own rendering engine - e.g. Firefox for Android has one as far as I remember.

If you need an Android app that runs on 2.1+ that I only see the possibility to embed an web-renderer in your app or use client side chart generation instead. The are some libraries available that allows you to do so:

- http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/
- http://code.google.com/p/droidcharts/

Both libraries are plain Java libraries that do not rely on JavaScript - hence they are independent of the WebKit version the OS contains.

Comment: This is not an option, since I, as the developer, must be sure that my app works on all the devices with OS version 2.1+.